# Why opencv show an empty windows instead of image

Tags: python, opencv

Here is my code

```
Import cv2
Path="D:\\opencv\\spm.jpg"
Img=cv2.imread(path)
Cv2.waitKey(0)
Cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: also please post entire code, because that's not the way to show images

Comment: Sorry I miss one line after read
Cv2.imshow('Image', img)

Comment: You are mixing `cv2` with `Cv2`

Comment: Isn't python case-sensitive? Try Img=cv2.imread(Path) with Path instead of path

Answer (score 2):

there are some syntax errors in your code and the important part is that you are not showing the image.

```
import cv2
path="D:\\opencv\\spm.jpg"
Img=cv2.imread(path)
cv2.imshow("img", Img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```